# How can i get file name inside "content-disposition" from a Response headers?

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post

Headers are sending filename="name.xlsx" inside the content-disposition but how can I set that name to the file that im downloading?

> component.ts:

```
  public getAccordo(event: any): any {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.accordiService.getAccordo(this.filter).subscribe(
      data => {
        const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
        const anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      anchor.download = name

        anchor.click(); 
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

> Service.ts

getAccordo(filtro: Filter) {

```
return this.http.post<any>(
    `${this.ENDPOINT}/export`,

    filter,

    {responseType : 'blob' as 'json'}

);}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the `headers` from the response you need to set `{observe: 'response'}` parameter in the `HttpOptions`.

```
this.http.post<any>(`${this.ENDPOINT}/export`, filter, {
     responseType : 'blob' as 'json',
     observe: 'response'
})
```

And then in the `subscribe` function you can get headers via `headers` property. Getting the name you can now set the name of the file.

Comment: I was using observe: 'response' but if I put that in my post when i open the excel file it says "the file is damaged or the extension is wrong", while it works fine without that :)

Comment: You need to access the body of the response. Maybe you also will need to manually parse to json